# Working code for uploading mp3 to server on android

Tags: android, networking, upload, android-volley

I have searched all over for a good code for uploading an mp3 or similar file to a php server and have tested over 10 samples but none has been successful so far. Most codes I have checked out are either full of bugs or use outdated libraries.

I would appreciate if anyone has a truly working code sample. Possibly one that uses volley or a similar library. Would appreciate any help or some code that points me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **loopj Android Asynchronous Http Client** [lib](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) for uploading file to the php server.
download the lib file from given link and put into your project's libs folder and use this code for uploading file.

```
public void postFile(){
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("fileTitle","MyFile1");
    params.put("file", new File("File Path Here")); // e.g Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.mp3"

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.post("http://www.yourweserviceurlhere.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }                                                                                                                                              
    }); 
}
```

**if you want progress of uploading. then you can use my custom design class.** for this also require [common io 2.4](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio24jar.htm) lib reference in converting HTTPresponse into string.

```
public class AsyncLoader {
private String url;
private LoaderCallBackHandler mCallback;
private Context mContext;
private RequestParams params;
private RequestHandle handle;

public interface LoaderCallBackHandler {        
    public void onStartUploading();
    public void uploadComplete(String response);
    public void failedWithError(Throwable error);
    public void progressUpdate(long bytesWritten, long bytesTotal);
    public void onCancle();
    public void onFinish();
}


public AsyncLoader(Context mContext,String url,RequestParams params, LoaderCallBackHandler callback) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.url = url;
    this.params = params;
    this.mCallback = callback;     

}

public void startTransfer() {       
    AsynchConfig.mClient.setTimeout(50000);        
    handle = AsynchConfig.mClient.post(mContext, url, params,handlerInterface);
}    
private ResponseHandlerInterface handlerInterface = new ResponseHandlerInterface() {

    @Override
    public void sendStartMessage() {
        if(mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onStartUploading();               
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void sendResponseMessage(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            // TODO convert in stream to JSONObject and do whatever you need to

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(instream, writer, Charset.defaultCharset());
            String theString = writer.toString();

            if(mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.uploadComplete(theString);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void sendSuccessMessage(int arg0, org.apache.http.Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendFailureMessage(int arg0, org.apache.http.Header[] arg1,
            byte[] arg2, Throwable error) {
            if(mCallback != null) {
                 mCallback.failedWithError(error);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void sendFinishMessage() {
        if(mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onFinish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sendProgressMessage(long bytesWritten, long bytesTotal) {
        if(mCallback != null) {             
            mCallback.progressUpdate(bytesWritten, bytesTotal);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequestURI(URI arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequestHeaders(org.apache.http.Header[] arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public URI getRequestURI() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public org.apache.http.Header[] getRequestHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendCancelMessage() {

        if(mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onCancle();
            mCallback.onFinish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRetryMessage(int retryNo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUsePoolThread(boolean usePoolThread) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUsePoolThread() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance,
            HttpResponse response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance,
            HttpResponse response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setTag(Object TAG) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object getTag() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
};

/**
* Cancel upload by calling this method
*/
public void cancel() throws Exception {
    AsynchConfig.mClient.cancelAllRequests(true);
    handle.cancel(true);

}
}
```

**Asynch config class**

```
public final class AsynchConfig {   
     public static AsyncHttpClient mClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
}
```

**Use**

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("fileTitle","MyFile1");
params.put("file", new File("File Path Here")); // e.g Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.mp3"

AsyncLoader asyncUploader = new AsyncLoader(this, "URL_HERE", params, callHandler);
asyncUploader.startTransfer();
```

**CallHandler Interface object**

```
LoaderCallBackHandler callHandler = new LoaderCallBackHandler() {

    @Override
    public void uploadComplete(String response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void progressUpdate(long bytesWritten, long bytesTotal) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartUploading() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void failedWithError(Throwable error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

**PHP service for handling uploaded file**

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_POST['fileTitle']) ) {
include './config.php';

//Randomly genrate file name
$stickerTmp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$file = md5(date("l, F d, Y h:i" ,time()) . (microtime())).".".end($stickerTmp);

//geting the temp location of file
$filetemploc=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

//path for uploading to the specific location
$pathandname="file_store/".$file;

// moving the file to specified path
$resultUpload = move_uploaded_file($filetemploc, $pathandname);

// if file is successfully moved to over specified path then insert the reference into the DB
if($resultUpload == TRUE) {
    //echo "File has been moved from : ". $filetemploc . " to  :".$pathandname;

    $qInsert = "INSERT INTO file_lists values (null,'".$_POST['fileTitle']."','".$file."') ";
    mysql_query($qInsert);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out asap but will appreciate if you can add the PHP code for receiving the file on the server.

Comment: Thanks. Was just about to post that it actually worked with my own php code. This is the is best and simplest file upload code I have seen so far. So easy and fast. Thanks again. I havent tried your custom class but the function worked fine. Will also try it for large files and see how it goes.